# I can't figure out why my PHP Session variables are being overwritten on page redirect

Tags: php, session, variables, post, get

I have a page using session variables that are created from user form input via the POST method. 
The session variables are being created properly using this code:

(I am collecting a zip code via an input on a form)

```
<form name="zipinput" id="zipform" method="post" action="" target="_blank" onsubmit="return valZip();"/>     
 <input id="zip" name="zip" class="zipfield" type="text" value="" />
 </form>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
$_SESSION['zip'] = $_POST['zip'];
if(isset($_SESSION['zip'])) {
$zipcode = $_SESSION['zip'];
}
```

This works fine. But when I go from page1.php to page2.php, the variables are erased. I thought the whole point of session variables was to be able to use them from page to page without _GET or _POST in the URL. I am also including: session_start();
at the top of my php pages.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: is `$_SESSION['zip'] = $_POST['zip']` on every page?

Comment: I have a file called "token.php" that i call on every page. inside that file, i define the variables. So yes its on every page.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're assigning a value to the session whether or not a zip value was actually provided. If not zip parameter is presesnt, you just write in a blank, which erases the previous zip. You'd want to do:

```
if (isset($_POST['zip'])) {
   $_SESSION['zip'] = $_POST['zip'];
}
$zip = $_SESSION['zip'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['zip'])
$_SESSION['zip'] = $_POST['zip'];
if(isset($_SESSION['zip'])) {
$zipcode = $_SESSION['zip'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the above worked...however i must add a few things that I am trying to accomplish

Comment: But in my form, I am setting the action (on submit) to an external server that manages the redirect and tracks my visitors

action="http://trackingdomain.com" 

So it goes from my main domain ----> zip input -----> tracking domain ----back to main domain. 

This is overwriting the session variables (again). I feel it should work because I'm not trying to read the variables from my tracking domain, but just redirect through it. Since the sessions were set, i'd think i could continue to read them on subsequent pages. No luck though...
Any more ideas? Thanks for the previous help again.

Answer (score 0):

instead of just having session_start() at the top of the page, try having

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)):
    session_start();
endif;
```

Comment: this is not true, you should start session on each request, and data in session won't be overwritten if you are using session_start();

Answer (score 0):

You must start a session on all pages. This is a good candidate for being put in an init file to arbitrarily be loaded in all pages before any other page content.. like in the header.

If you don't, the session you saved will be destroyed upon page redirect.